# Presto / AWS Athena : create Array of different types inside the SELECT

Tags: aggregate, presto, amazon-athena

I currently have an AWS Athena query that looks like this:

```
SELECT array_agg(ROW(n.stop_sequence, n.stop_name, n.stop_lat, n.stop_lon))
FROM ...
GROUP BY ...
```

The output right now looks like this:

```
[{field0=39, field1=Name, field2=41.838512, field3=12.437013}, {field0=...,...},...]
```

Is there a way to modify (not make another query to modify the current output) the `SELECT` in a way so the output looks like this instead?

```
[[39, Name, 41.838512, 12.437013}, [...],...]
```

I tried using `ARRAY` instead of `ROW` but that doesn't work because the array needs same type elements. Also I don't want to make a second query to modify the output either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found out already, `array` needs to be homogeneous, of some type, and there is no common supertype in SQL. An anonymous `row` (`row` with unnamed fields) is what you want, but this is currently how it's being printed

```
presto> SELECT ROW(42, true, 'Presto SQL');
                    _col0
---------------------------------------------
 {field0=42, field1=true, field2=Presto SQL}
(1 row)
```

You can track issue https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/4587 for improving this.